# Query with variables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding in PHP and I'm having some troubles with variables in MySQL query. In particular i'm trying to pass a value from a SELECT query to an UPDATE query.

The query that I'm running is:

```
$queryUpddateMinimumSaving = '
    SELECT 
        @monthlyVal:= monthlyValue,
        @fixedElementType:= codElementType,
        @username:= username
    FROM fixedElement
    WHERE codElement = '.$codFixedElement.';

    UPDATE bankAccount SET
    IF(
        @fixedElementType = 1,
        minimumSaving = IF((minimumSaving - @monthlyVal) >=0,
            minimumSaving - @monthlyVal,
            0
        )
        minimunSaving = minimumSaving + @monthlyVal
    )
    WHERE username = @username
;';
```

Even running the query in PHPMyAdmin the query doesn't work.
MySql shows me this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'IF(
> @fixedElementType = 1,
> minimumSaving = IF((minimumSaving -' at line 2

But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong ^^"
I'm looking in MySql doc and the query looks right

May you help me?
Thanks

Comment: What's the point of the SELECT ?

Comment: After `SET` MySQL is expecting a list of column's names to be upgraded and the new values to be set. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: @strawberry - I need the value of the selected rows. Can i get them with MySql or have I to store them into PHP variables an then run the UPDATE query with the PHP variables?

Comment: @SeeoX so I have to put the nested IF after the column's name, right?

Like this : UPDATE bankAccount SET minimumSaving = IF(condition,IF(condition, ...) ...)

Comment: You don't need a SELECT (as far as I can tell)

Comment: You cannot have two queries in one statement. You need to run them separately. I would probably go with a join on this, though.

Comment: @aynber - And can the variables be used from the query in the second statement?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The query values don't disappear until the connection/session does.

Comment: It's odd anyway to use mysql variables in application code.

Comment: @aynber - Thanks, i'll try with the JOIN

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Why can't you do this as a singular `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use single query for this problem:

```
UPDATE bankAccount 
JOIN fixedElement ON fixedElement.username = bankAccount.username
SET
    minimunSaving = IF(
        codElementType = 1,
        GREATEST(minimumSaving - monthlyValue, 0),
        minimumSaving + monthlyValue
    )
WHERE codElement = '.$codFixedElement.';
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! :D
You just forgot a "," after <GREATEST(minimumSaving - monthlyValue, 0)
>